# What does a file MD5 Hash represent?

Tags: file, hash, cryptography, md5

I know a file's MD5 Hash is like a digital fingerprint used to confirm integrity and authenticity. There are many utilities to get the MD5 Hash of a file but what does that hash base on? File size? File low level binaries? Code?

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate, the TLDR is that it's the binary contents of the file only.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is a so-called cryptographic hash function.

This basically means that you can give in any bitstring as input for the function, and you will get out a fixed-size bitstring (128-bit in the case of MD5) as output. The output is usually called "digest".

The digest depends solely on the input and nothing else. Thus in itself it can be used as an integrity proof, but not as authenticity, **if** the underlying hash function has the necessary properties (in this case [collision-resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance)). This means that for two different outputs the digest itself should be also different. The problem is that the digest's size is fixed, which in turn means that with sufficient number of messages it will always be possible to find a collision (i.e., two different inputs yielding the same output).

One should also note that there is nowadays no justification to use MD5, as weaknesses have been discovered (namely post-fix collision attacks). Also using SHA-256/512 on modern hardware is usually faster then MD5.

**Shortly:** the output of the cryptographic hash functions (and so MD5's) depends on the input bitstring.

**Update:** based on your comment for the other answer, you are looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum

In general, the algorithm runs over the file and it's output is checksum, that means that if someone changes a bit in the file the checksum will be changed. so it's a way to validate that the file you looking at is the file you think you looking at and lowering the probability that someone put a melicius code in it

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that post doesn't answer my question. My question is what does a MD5Sum really "process" to output what it does. If I encrypt a string the input is the string and the output is the encrypted result. But if the input is a file, what does the md5sum take as input to encrypt?

Comment: the FILE - as a long set of bytes

Comment: hence: input:FILE, output:hash string